# Self Join to subtract customer_out_time of a row from customer_in_time of the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query was written to provide free time of a waiter between two consecutive customers ( for the first customer of a day it will be 0 and then just subtract customer_out_time from next customer_in_time.Where as the query is giving the wrong result as it is even summing the values. I am not able to detect the error. Any suggestions?

### I Can't Use Lag as my sql server is 2008

Output of the query

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| Name              Customer_In_Time         Customer_Out_Time    Free Time                 |  
+------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| Nikhil, Tiwari    2020-03-03 14:30:00.000   2020-03-03 15:11:00.000   0    |  
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 08:10:00.000   2020-03-03 08:35:46.650   0    |  
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 08:33:12.000   2020-03-03 09:35:02.000   -2   |  
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 09:22:00.000   2020-03-03 10:30:19.447   47   |  
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 11:54:24.000   2020-03-03 13:44:07.000   199  |  
| Ayish, Jain       2020-03-03 14:16:04.000   2020-03-03 16:23:01.000   341  |  
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 07:34:52.000   2020-03-03 08:48:47.000   0    |  
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 10:30:31.000   2020-03-03 11:48:26.000   102  |  
| Harsh,Gupta       2020-03-03 12:37:43.000   2020-03-03 13:35:43.000   229  |  
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Required Output for free time:

0

0

-2
-13
84
32
0
102

```
Declare @start date, @end date
set @start='01/01/2020'
set @end='03/03/2020'

select Waiter,t.Customer_In_Time,Customer_Out_Time,
       coalesce(sum(datediff(minute, prev_cot, Customer_in_time)), 0) as free_minutes
from (select t.*,
             tprev.Customer_out_time as prev_cot
      from t outer apply
           (select top (1) t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.Waiter = t.Waiter and t2.date = t.date and
                  t2.Customer_in_time < t.Customer_in_time
                  
            order by t.Waiter, t2.Customer_in_time 
           ) tprev
     ) t
     where t.date between @start and @end
     and Waiter is not Null
     and Room_no not like '%TH%'
    
group by Waiter, Customer_In_Time,Customer_Out_Time
order by t.Waiter,t.Customer_In_time
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Needs more description to support the question.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your code that it's only treating the first row as the previous row for the whole group but we need to pick the just previous row, so, we need a numbering function to create the numbers within the groups and select just the last row.

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create the record numbers for each waiter and then can select easily the previous row based on the `rn` value.

```
select t.waiter, t.Customer_In_Time, t.Customer_Out_Time
 , row_number() over (partition by t.waiter order by t.waiter, t.Customer_In_Time) rn
into #temp 
from @t t
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36a70cd5281455494eb027e6f449b676)**.

Comment: Any solution for without the temp file @sacse

Comment: @PallaviJha you can use common table expression (CTE) like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd14cbe03c1ebcd0bcd907e2bef49c39).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(minute,
                lag(Customer_Out_Time, 1, Customer_Out_Time) over (partition by waiter order by Customer_In_Time) as prev_cot
                Customer_In_Time
               ) as diff_minutes
from t;
```